# Issue in calling of ng-controller in angular-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

`HTML 5 mobile app` which i am making using `AngularJs` `JQuery Mobile` now my structure of app is looks like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="page1" data-role="page" ng-controller="one">
        <!-- Page Content -->
    </div>
    <div id="page2" data-role="page" ng-controller="one">
        <!-- Page Content -->
    </div>
    <div id="page3" data-role="page" ng-controller="two">
        <!-- Page Content -->
    </div>
    <div id="page4" data-role="page" ng-controller="two">
        <!-- Page Content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

So now is there any possibility that i write `ng-controller` with `<body>` instead of writing with every `page` `div`because if i write with every page then controller functions call multiple times (in above example call 2 times)

Comment: Why wouldn't you use routes for this? It'd help separate the "Pages" from the controllers. Try following this tutorial. Helped me a lot: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: You can declare the controller on `<body>`.

Comment: @itamar its webapp and i think route not working without server?
my client does not want any server if there is a way then it will helpful if you provide.

Comment: @apohl declare on `<body>`  like `<body ng-controller="one two">` ?

Comment: No, you would have to use just one controller. Otherwise, you could just have a different controller for every page.

Comment: this is a `J Query Mobile` single page structure that is the problem

Comment: I've worked on a JQuery Mobile/AngularJS app before, and the way Jquery mobile generates code, it makes it quite a bit more difficult to use angular.

Comment: yeah same problem mu controller function calls many times